# App Store Approval for Application That Requires Authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

For an app specific to a closed system like for internal usage within an organization, what are the concerns of the approval process at the App Store? The application requires user to login, and the login details are provided internally, and there is no signup feature.

Comment: Apps used only internal within an organization should not be in the app store in the first place. Most likely they will reject your app because it should live under a enterprise account.

Comment: The organization is not in the US and does not have a Duns number, so enterprise account is not the option we can go for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's submission policies, not programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must provide a temporary login to the reviewer; you can do so in the "additional information" field at the bottom of the iTunes Connect form you use to upload your application. I've done that in previous apps and it works perfectly well. Once your app is approved, just disable the account.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the important consideration.